# Неправильно работает кнопка Update в active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В `active_admin` партиалом создана форма ввода информации:

```
<%= semantic_nested_form_for @item, :url => admin_items_path do |f| %>
  <fieldset class="inputs">
  <ol>
    <%= f.input :category %></br>
    <%= f.input :title  %>
  <%= f.input :photo1 %>
  <%= f.input :photo2 %>
</ol>
</fieldset>
  <%= f.fields_for :ItemColors do |i| %>
    <fieldset class="inputs">
      <ol>
    <%= i.input :DetailColor %>
    <%= i.input :size,  :input_html => { :size => "10" } %>
    <%= i.link_to_remove "remove" %>
  </ol>
</fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "add", :ItemColors %>
  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

При создании нового `Item` все нормально создает и перебрасывает на страницу созданного `Item`, но если делать `update` существующего происходит ошибка `routes`, хотя такой путь существует:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/admin/items"
```

Если поменять первую строку партиала на:

`<%= semantic_nested_form_for @item, :url => admin_items_path(@item) do |f| %>`

Получается:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/admin/items.150" #или другой item_id
```

rake routes:

```
batch_action_admin_items POST /admin/items/batch_action(.:format)             admin/items#batch_action
        admin_items GET     /admin/items(.:format)           admin/items#index            
                    POST    /admin/items(.:format)           admin/items#create
     new_admin_item GET     /admin/items/new(.:format)       admin/items#new                
    edit_admin_item GET     /admin/items/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/items#edit        
         admin_item GET     /admin/items/:id(.:format)       admin/items#show           
                    PUT     /admin/items/:id(.:format)       admin/items#update               
                    DELETE  /admin/items/:id(.:format)       admin/items#destroy
```

Подскажите, из-за чего такое может быть?

**UPD**

Непонятно, откуда берётся точка в адресе запроса.

Comment: Задавая такой вопрос нужно показывать что выдаёт `rake routes`. Иначе можно гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, добавил rake routes, в общем-то я его не добавил сразу потому-что все роуты в данном случае идут от самого active_admin: ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю тут вместо `:url => admin_items_path` нужно `:url => admin_item_path(@item)`

Comment: тогда получаю 
No route matches [PUT] "/admin/items.150"
150 - id item

Comment: странно, там точки не должно быть

Comment: мне тоже кажется что не должно быть) , непонятно откуда она берется

Comment: как оказалось, для Update должно быть так: admin_item_path()